# MySQL Character Encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a form from which i am taking user details.I am seeing that when the user enters character like  ' there is an entry in the table but the character is entered as ? in the DB.
For Example : If a user enter : BCG [Nov-14 - Current].This is getting entered as BCG [Nov?14 ? Current] in the table.I am using MySQL.Please Help

Comment: I believe your question is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384180/how-to-deal-with-quotes-and-apostrophes-for-string-comparison-in-mysql-so-they-m

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database table encoding is set to utf8. You can verify by running dumping the table schema from command line:

bash $ mysqldump -p   > debug.sql

For older MySQL version, the default encoding is latin1

Comment: Hi Vic,You are correct.My default encoding is latin1.So how can i change the default encoding and also now if i change my default encoding to utf8 then can it impact many other factor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/357092

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL Workbench, right-click on the schema and choose "Alter Schema...". Now you will have a select list labelled "Collation". Choose utf8 and click on Apply.